# Entity framework select an existing item and only pull back one of its fields to update

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to do something that should be "simple", I want to pull out a piece of data from my database but I only want to pull out the description (the database table for this item has first name, last name, address etc etc).

So when I call my database call I want to just grab the description and then update it, I don't want to grab anything else as this will cost network power and may cause lag if uses multiple times in a few seconds.

Here is my code that i'm trying to fix

```
using (var context = new storemanagerEntities())
        {
            var stock = context.stocks.Where(x => x.id == model.Id).Select(
                x => new stock()
                {
                    description = x.description
                }).FirstOrDefault();

            stock.description = model.Description;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The error I am catching is this

```
**The entity or complex type 'StoreManagerModel.stock' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.**
```

I'm sure using the "new" keyword is probably the problem, but does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

--update

This code works, but it doesn't seem to actually update the database

```
    public void UpdateDescription(StockItemDescriptionModel model)
    {
        using (var context = new storemanagerEntities())
        {
            var stock = context.stocks.Where(x => x.id == model.Id)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(
                x => new stock
                {
                    description = x.description
                }).FirstOrDefault();

            stock.description = model.Description;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

At the moment it would seem it maybe my MySQl driver which is 6390, it seems to work in another version I tried, sorry I haven't found the answer yet

Comment: Would aforementioned lag really be noticable? Most of the lag associated with databases comes from connecting to it, not executing a query or retrieving results

Comment: Well lag is always an issue, but I would still like a answer, as I feel it would make my code much neater

Comment: Well, concerning your error, you're trying to create a non tracked type inside (For all intents and purposes) a SQL query. You need to turn your Linq-To-SQL into Linq-To-Entities by using `.ToList()` after your `.Where` call

Comment: There is actually a practical purpose for this, if your entity has `VARBINARY(MAX)` or similar and it's actually prohibitive to bring it back from the database ... only to ignore it.

Comment: That's fine by me, but OP said he wanted to address 'lag', not database limitations :P

Comment: You'll experience "lag" if your application is waiting for a 6mb binary blob to be transferred along with your entity from the database. You can have the world's fastest database but lose out to an ADSL connection.

Comment: For what it's worth there are extensions to the Entity Framework that make this possible: https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Batch-Update-and-Delete

Comment: *This code works, but it doesn't seem to actually update the database* Well yeah, you just make a new object and leave it hanging in the ether.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it even without getting any entity from the database by creating a *stub entity*:

```
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

// Create stub entity:
var stock = new stock { id = model.Id, description = model.Description };

// Attach stub entity to the context:
context.Entry(stock).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;

// Mark one property as modified.
context.Entry(stock).Property("description").IsModified = true;

context.SaveChanges();
```

Validation on save is switched off, otherwise EF will validate the stub entity, which is very likely to fail because it may have required properties without values.

Of course it may be wise to check whether the entity does exist in the database at all, but that can be done by a cheap `Any()` query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't project to a mapped entity type during an L2E query, you would need to switch the context back to L2F. For optimal performance it's recommended to use `AsEnumerable` over `ToList` to avoid materializing the query too early e.g.

```
var stock = context.stocks.Where(x => x.id == model.Id)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new stock 
    {
        description = x.description
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

As to your actual problem, the above won't allow you to do this as is because you have effectively created a *non-tracking* entity. In order for EF to understand how to connect your entity to your DB you would need to attach it to the context - this would require that you also pull down the `Id` of the entity though i.e.

```
    Select(x => new stock
    {
        id = x.id,
        description = x.description
    })
    ...
    context.stocks.Attach(stock);
    stock.description = model.Description;
    context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Strictly speaking you can project in a L2E query, just not using a non-tracked/complex type (ie a class), but you can project to anonymous classes

Comment: @DanPantry you can project onto a complex type, you just can't project onto a mapped entity type. I have updated my answer to be more specific.

Comment: I tried this one and I get this error when trying to access stock.description = model.description Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @Canvas what's `null` in your case? `stock` or `model`?

Comment: Category is null it would seem

Comment: @Canvas that would appear to be out with the scope of my answer then because there is no mention of `Category`.

Comment: @James, apologies, didnt' mean to write 'complex types' I was just staring at the error too long

Comment: i do apologize, i mean stock :), i'm using the same code for category also :D

Comment: @Canvas so if `stock` is `null` then that means your query is yielding no results, most likely a problem with the `Where` clause.

Comment: was working fine with my first piece of code i have shown in my post

Comment: @Canvas so you are suggesting that `AsEnumerable` is the problem? Strange, so if you replace it with a call to `ToList` does it work?

Comment: .ToList seems has the same problem, object is set to null

Comment: @Canvas that leads me back to your query being the problem then...`ToList` is you saying *"ok go ahead and execute this query on the DB and give me the results"*, if there are no results then the DB is returning no records. I would triple check your query.

Comment: @Canvas yep, and the reason it doesn't update is because you didn't read my answer properly. Re-read it (specifically from the second paragraph).

Comment: Well i'm looking at the stock that is created, and all of the fields are 0 or null, if i attach that in, won't it re-write the data that is already there?

Comment: When I do the attach i get this error "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key"

Comment: With regards to updating all the various properties, I think EF should be smart enough to know which ones have been changed. Hmm it already exists... have you already pulled down that stock item using the same context?